# cakephp 'inList' validation not working

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, model, cakephp-1.3

I find that the validation rule 'inList' in cakephp 1.3.10 is not working properly. I Have this on my validation

```
 'vote' => array(
        'rule' => 'inList', array(1,2,3), 
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'required' => true,
        'message' => 'error_vote'
  )
```

This is on my View

```
echo $form->input('User.vote', array(
         'type' => 'radio',
         'legend' => __("form_vote", "true"),
         'class' => 'vote',
         'options' => array('1' => 'One', '2' => 'two', '3' => 'Three' ),
        ));
```

Can someone let meknow what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a syntax error, `rule` needs to be an array:

```
'rule' => array('inList', array(1,2,3))
```

Comment: Just for clarification, doesn't throw error because the `vote` array is correct for PHP, but Cake doesn't recognize because this case, `vote` have an `array(1,2,3)` item with no key specified. Maybe a glitch in the validation library, because it should check all the keys first.